# How to add extended properties in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, extended-properties

Is it possible to add a kind of Extended Properties in tables and/or columns in PostgreSQL as we can do in SQL Server?

I've been looking for this in Google, but I can't find anything about it.

I want to describe columns (data dictionary) and add parameters that I can later match by reflection with my properties in Java.

Comment: Not familiar with MSSQL, but it sounds like you could build a reasonable approximation by putting [JSON data](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html) in [comment strings](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-comment.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postgres (and many other DBMS) does this through a DDL statement `comment on`.

To attach a comment to a table, view, column, foreign key (pretty much everything) use `comment on`, e.g:

```
comment on table orders is 'Our orders';
comment on column orders.amount is 'Total amount of this order';
```

More details in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-comment.html

The JDBC driver will return this information in the `remarks` column in the result of e.g. `getTables()` or `getColumns()`

To access the values through SQL, use the functions provided by Postgres:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-COMMENT-TABLE

Comment: Thank you. But what about adding my own properties or annotations into a column? Comments would be useful for a data dictionary (half of my question). As far as I know, the columns will be created in lowercase but I want something like Pascal Case (e.g. EmployeeName). I can use the double quotes to force the name of my column. But then queries should always include double quoted for tables and columns. I'm using PostgreSQL 9.4 and pgAdminIII. I don't want this format "employee_social_security_number" or even "employeesocialsecuritynumber".

Comment: I want to create my java properties easily and I thought that reading these kind of annotations from DB would be faster as I would keep my SQL queries simple

Comment: @MaximusDecimus: you should get used to `snake_case`. It's really the only (and in my opinion the best) solution (and is used with essentially every other DBMS like Oracle, DB2, Firebird, Vertica, ...). Btw: you can essentially put anything in the comments, as far as I know there is no length limit

Comment: Thank you so much for answer. Really appreciated. I'm learning new products other than MSSQL. You made a strong point with Oracle, DB2 ans others.